# How to check if header previously present or not

Tags: ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, email-headers

I am sending multiple emails through a function in `mailer.rb` through a loop. And before each mail, I am setting an `X-SMTPAPI` header, as they all are going through a single function, the header is not getting reset after a mail.

I got on google that setting that header key to nil resets the whole header, but the problem is coming for the first email in the loop. I don't know how to check if a header is already present or not.

I just want to know, how to check if a header is previously there or not in ActionMailer.

Update:- here is my mailer class code(class Edumailer < ActionMailer::Base)

```
def mailer(....)
    headers "X-SMTPAPI" => { unique_args: { webhook_id: webhook.id }}.to_json
    mail(to: to, subject: subject, body: body, bcc: bcc, cc: cc, content_type: content_type)
end



def publish_lecture(emails, course_name, course_id, body)
    emails.each {|email|
        self.mailer(:to => email, :body => body, :content_type => "text/html", :subject => "Content Added into course #{course_name}",webhookable_type: "Course", webhookable_id: course_id ,purpose: __method__.to_s).deliver
}
end
```

so sending multiple emails through publish_lecture and setting header in mailer method before mail, so as it move further,all ahead emails includes header of previous mail.

Which I want to reset after each email.

Comment: You may want to share the mailer code including the "single function" you reference. This sounds like an X-Y problem but there's really no way to tell without code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @MarkThomas I added the code. Hope it will help you to understand my problem better.